# Why does my Attach() method trigger a "Entity already exists" InvalidOperationException?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

This has stumped me for a few hours. I'm rewriting a Winforms desktop app to support an ASP.NET Core website. The app stores some tables locally in a LiteDB cache, and calls a "using" DBContext to get data.

The desktop app uses a `TaxAccount` abstract class, which is inherited by `Household` and `Business`.

On client search, the app calls GetAccount() to display a single user account. Since the DB can be slow, the cache is updated in the background. Here's the method.

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieve a single account from cache. Later, replace the account object with object from server.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="accountID"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public TaxAccount GetAccount(int accountID)
        {
            var accounts = Cache.GetCollection<TaxAccount>();
            var account = accounts.FindById(accountID);

            if (GetSingleAccountTask == null || GetSingleAccountTask.IsCompleted)
            {
                GetSingleAccountTask = Task.Run(() => UpdateAccount(account));
            }

            return account;

            void UpdateAccount(TaxAccount account)
            {
                using (var serverContext = new ApplicationDbContext(ServerOptions))
                {
                    var found = serverContext.Accounts
                        .Include(X => X.Users)
                        .FirstOrDefault(X => X.Id == account.Id);

                    account = found;

                    if (found != null)
                    {
                        accounts.Update(found);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        accounts.Delete(account.Id);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

I'd like to update single properties of the `TaxAccount` entity. To do so, I use `Attach(taxAccount)`, this ideally should update just the property I want.

```cs
        public void UpdatePrivateLink(TaxAccount taxAccount, string link)
        {
            // Retrieve collection from cache.
            var accounts = Cache.GetCollection<TaxAccount>();
            using (var serverContext = new ApplicationDbContext(ServerOptions))
            {
                // Attach taxAccount to server context.
                serverContext.Attach(taxAccount);
                taxAccount.PrivateFolderLink = link;
                // Update server.
                serverContext.SaveChanges();
                // Update cache.
                accounts.Update(taxAccount);
            }    
        }
```

This doesn't work. It creates a `System.InvalidOperationException` : `The instance of entity type 'Household' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1}' is already being tracked`. BUT I CAN'T FIND THE ENTITY.

Here's the list of things I've tried:

- changing the Get() query to .AsNoTracking() does nothing.
- serverContext.ChangeTracker.Clear() does nothing.
- serverContext.Entry(taxAccount) returns a state of EntityState.Detached
- there is no metadata in serverContext.ChangeTracker.ToDebugString()
- serverContext.Find(taxAccount.Id) makes a database hit
- retrieving directly from the LiteDB cache using accounts.FindbyId(taxAccount.Id) creates the same error.

What's worse, if I create a `new Household()` with the same id, then all of a sudden it does work!

```cs
var account = new Household() { Id = taxAccount.Id };
serverContext.Attach(account);
account.PrivateFolderLink = link;
serverContext.SaveChanges();

// Then we have to save in cache.
taxAccount.PrivateFolderLink = link;
accounts.Update(taxAccount);
```

This work-around makes no sense to me. Why does EF think `taxAccount` is tracked on a brand-new DbContext? Why can't I get rid of this tracking without creating a new object?

Would appreciate advice.

EDIT:

- serverContext.Accounts.Local contains no elements.

EDIT:
This test is the simplest implementation that still fails.

```cs
        public void AttachTest(int accountID, string link)
        {
            var accounts = Cache.GetCollection<TaxAccount>();
            var acct = accounts.FindById(accountID);

            using (var serverContext = new ApplicationDbContext(ServerOptions))
            {
                serverContext.Attach(acct);
                acct.PrivateFolderLink = link;
                serverContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

For full debugging: I'm testing on .NET 5.0 console app, the EF version is 5.0.13 hosted on a .NET Standard 2.1 library.

Here's the TaxAccount model I'm using.

```cs
    public abstract class TaxAccount
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool Archived { get; set; } = false;
        public string PrivateFolderLink { get; set; }

        public List<AppUser> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public class Household : TaxAccount
    {
    }

    public class Business : TaxAccount
    {
        [EmailAddress, MaxLength(500)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(500)]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(1000)]
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

In my ApplicationDbContext, the only `fluent` logic is to mark the discriminator.

```cs
            // Tax Account abstract class.
            builder.Entity<TaxAccount>().HasDiscriminator()
                .HasValue<Household>(nameof(Household))
                .HasValue<Business>(nameof(Business))
                .IsComplete(true);

            builder.Entity<TaxAccount>()
                .Property("Discriminator")
                .HasMaxLength(50);
```

Comment: It could be that the error message is misleading, and the error actually mean the entity is already being tracked, but by another `DbContext`. You should detach it when caching anyway since you don't want a `DbContext` stay longer than it should.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. All of my queries use .AsNoTracking() by default. If they were tracked, wouldn't the `new TaxAccount()` also cause problems?

Comment: In that case could you provide a simpler project/[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (maybe on Github) that can reproduce the problem? Sorry the code pieces you provide is too hard to test and diagnose the problem.

Comment: Cleptus, please see my comment on Shu si. @Luke Vo, sorry bout that. This came up during a bad sprint - I'll see if I can provide a better example in the morning.

Comment: EDIT : You can replace the first GetMethod with `var account = accounts.FindById(accountID);`. I just confirmed it still causes the same problems. I've added an updated test that fails.

Comment: Can you post you TaxAccount model? and also which version EF do you using?

Comment: Please see the EDIT. As for version, I'm using 5.0.13 loaded to .NET Standard 2.1.

Comment: and please post your ServerOptions?

Comment: They're the default options for SQL Server, ServerOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .UseSqlServer(_ServerConnString)
                .Options;

Comment: By Discriminator you only have TaxAccount table (no Household or Bussiness) in your database, yes?

Comment: maybe you should use this ``builder.Ignore<Household>();`` and ``builder.Ignore<Business>();``

Comment: With your code, simply attaching and saving `new Household()` is fine. It must be something in the  instance returned from the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting this morning, I figured it out! Luckily, it has nothing to do with the cache or other DbContexts!

The class `TaxAccount` has an `List<AppUser>`, which has a property `Accounts`, which is an `List<TaxAccount>`. This many-to-many relationship is creating a cycle within the `Attach()` method that EF Core doesn't deal well with. To prove this, I wrote two tests, both of which worked!

```cs
public void AttachTest(int accountID, string link)
        {
            var accounts = Cache.GetCollection<TaxAccount>();
            var acct = accounts.FindById(accountID);
            // We set the Users relation to be null.
            acct.Users = null;

            using (var serverContext = new ApplicationDbContext(ServerOptions))
            {
                serverContext.Attach(acct);
                acct.PrivateFolderLink = link;
                serverContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

```cs
public void AttachTestNullUsers(int accountID, string link)
        {
            var accounts = Cache.GetCollection<TaxAccount>();
            var acct = accounts.FindById(accountID);
            // For each user, the Accounts is null, this also breaks the relationship.
            acct.Users.ForEach(X => X.Accounts = null);

            using (var serverContext ...
        }
```

Now, there's two follow-up questions to this:

1. Is this better than creating a new instance of `TaxAccount` and attaching that?
2. How does this deal with `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operations for the many-to-many relationship?

---

1. Probably not. Setting `acct.Users = null` is an unintended outcome, and it'll be easy to forget to restore that relationship once the command is done. OTOH, initializing a `new TaxAccount(taxAccount.Id)` is a light operation with no effects on the base object.
2. Poorly, after some testing, `Attach()` is not a good idea if you want add or remove many-to-many objects. Lookup then update is your best option here.

Answer (score -1):

### From the [Microsoft Wiki:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.update?view=efcore-5.0)

> Begins tracking the given entity and entries reachable from the given entity using >the Modified state by default, but see below for cases when a different state will >be used.
>
> Generally, no database interaction will be performed until SaveChanges() is called.

My guess is, that the Account is tracked until the changes are saved.

Comment: Hey Shu si, unfortunately this doesn't help. None of my "Get" queries are tracked. They either come from the cache or from a .AsNoTracking() query.

Comment: You could improve your answer adding that tracking is their default behavior and that they could add `.AsNoTracking()` in their `Cache.GetCollection<T>()` to avoid it getting tracked. @RamneekSingh Consider adding your cache and `accounts.FindById` methods code... Does it have `AsNoTracking`?

Comment: @Cleptus, accounts.FindById is a LiteDB method, it's shouldn't affect what EF Core is doing since LiteDB is a separate library.

Comment: Please don't post guesses as answers. Wait until you can post comments.

Comment: Ok I'm Sorry. Won't post answers like this again.